# How can I reset windows powershell/command prompt, like reset in bash?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe, vagrant

When I use vagrant on Windows I will sometimes find that newlines aren't respected properly.  This is typically after doing a `vagrant ssh`.  So text ends up looking like

```
This machine with the name 'default' was not found 
                                                   configured for this environment.
```

In bash when this kind of terminal goofup happens I can run `reset` and it clears and resets the terminal settings.   How can I do something similar in Powershell/CMD and not have to kill the window and start a new powershell/cmd session?

Comment: Actually, "reset" does something else (reset the console settings, including codepages etc). Usually you use "reset" when dumping garbage from a binary files renders your console unusable. If you just want to clear the screen, use "clear" (or press Ctrl+L).

Answer (score 3):

While not a replacement for the Linux `reset` command, [this PowerShell script](https://gist.github.com/drichardson/195db36121cf4de10be03c9fc1198b63) will update your PowerShell terminal window buffer width to match the window width, which may fix the alignment issues you mentioned.

I use this script to remove the horizontal scroll bar that appears when I resize down the window horizontally.

```
function reset {
    Set-Buffer-Width-To-Screen-Width
    Clear-Host
}

function Set-Buffer-Width-To-Screen-Width {
    $h = Get-Host
    $ui = $h.UI.RawUI
    $bufferSize = $ui.BufferSize
    $windowSize = $ui.WindowSize
    $bufferSize.Width = $windowSize.Width
    $ui.BufferSize = $bufferSize
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `CLS` in both the command prompt and PowerShell.

Note: In PowerShell, `CLS` is technically an alias of the command `Clear-Host`.

> [CLS Clear the screen - Windows CMD - SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/cls.html)
>
> Syntax: `CLS`
>
> If CLS is redirected to file, console or executed through FOR /F it will print a line feed character (ASCII 10).
>
> Errorlevels:
>   If the screen is successfully cleared %ERRORLEVEL% =
>   unchanged (this is a bug) If a bad switch is given = 1

> [Clear-Host - PowerShell - SS64](https://ss64.com/ps/clear-host.html) Clear-Host
>
> Clear the screen.
>
> Syntax: `Clear-Host`
>
> Standard Aliases for Clear-Host: `clear`, `cls`

Comment: This just clears the screen.  It doesn't reset the terminal settings.   reset on linux does more than just clear the screen?