# command line not being redrawn correctly in powershell

Tags: powershell, reset

This morning when I started typing in a powershell window that I left open overnight, the entire input is re-echoed onto the line for each character typed, so for example when I type `Get-History` I see

> GGeGetGet-Get-HGet-HiGet-HisGet-HistGet-HistoGet-HistorGet-History

I suspect the problem is caused by the fact that I had been sshed into a remote system and was using vi and then the connection was severed after a certain amount of idle time.

How can I reset the window, aside from closing it down?  I don't see a menu bar, and when I right-click on the title bar, none of the menu items (eg Properties) seems to have anything helpful.

EDIT: I suppose this question is very similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1212029/how-can-i-reset-windows-powershell-command-prompt-like-reset-in-bash) which did not receive any satisfactory answers

MORE EDITS: I am running it inside a virtual desktop in Citrix Workspace.  The `Get-History` command runs ok despite the crazy echoing.

Comment: What terminal/console is powershell running in?

Comment: Is the duplicate text actually getting entered into the input buffer/does it run when you hit enter, or is it just visual? Usually you only need to clear the current window, buffer, and history via `Clear-Host` when strange characters are messing with the rendering.

Comment: Try running `powershell` to reload your runspace/session (not sure of the term). If you just want to keep your current credentials/session, you can run `Start-Process powershell` to open a new window as a child process.